# how to change crud without id in php html without changing other values

Tags: php, html

I tried to update single json file, it worked to change one value but the problem is that other data is always deleted, here's my code

```
// data.json before changing
{"username":"","email":"","password":null}

// data.json after changing
{"username":"sdsds","email":"","password":null}

// php code
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['update'])) {
$file = 'data.json';
$file_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$file_data['username'] = $_POST["username"];
$file_data['email']   = $_POST['email'];
$file_data['password']   = $_POST['password'];
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($file_data));
?>

//html code
                <!-- Example-->
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header justify-content-between align-items-center d-flex">
                    <h6 class="card-title m-0">UPDATE SETTING</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="username" class="form-label">USERNAME</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1" name="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="Email" class="form-label">EMAIL</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="1" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="Password" class="form-label">SITE PARAMETER</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="1" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="update" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / Example-->
```

what i want is how to change data of single json array without removing other values? if i only fill in password or e-mail, the other values will be removed

Comment: So then _check_ if the parameters originating from these fields are empty or not - and if they are, take the original value from the JSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your old value in the value attribute of input tag like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $file_data['username']; ?>" class="form-control" name="username">
```